# Running GLORP tests

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to get `GLORP` into the pharo 2.0 image. I managed to load `GLORP` , `PostgresV2` driver and then changed the `GlorpDatabaseLoginResource` default login params. After that, i started running the tests starting with PostgresV2 tests TestPGConnection in this i got 2 failures `testFieldConverter2` and `testFieldConverter3`.

after i ran the `GlorpTest`. here i got only 353 out of 674 tests passed. Is this normal? I am running the test using the testRunner. Any idea where i could have taken a possible bad step?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How did you load which versions of what packages on what platform? The question is currently unanswerable. Mailing list is much better for this, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got all test correct now. The probelm was in the image i was checking the `DateAndTime offset:` method was modified somehow (may be installing some other packages did that). So that was causing my Date And time related functions to fail. After i loaded all to a fresh image and ran it was like a fine piece of cake. :)